# Angular 2 Read backend URL from file in production

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have an Angular 2 app that connects to maven spring-boot backend through webservice, so I need to configure the backend URL somewhere in typescript code, but my problem is how do that after package all in the same jar for production.

To build the Angular App I'm using webpack.

Comment: Are you using the Angular CLI? If so, you can use its environment files as defined here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: Hi @Devorahk , no I'm not using Angular Cli

Comment: are your angular and back end in same app or run in differ app?

Comment: Hi Ali Akbar , yes both are in the same app

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse proxy like zuul to route your request to down service

for example in Angular you can call /api/users

and in zuul you can create route like this

```
routes:
    app:
      path: /api/**
      url: http://localhost:8082/app/
```